# Why does not std:string + int give compilation error?

Tags: gcc, stl, g++, stdstring, name-mangling

We just found our colleague thought he can add an integer to std::string and used such operation here and there in his code.

We don't see any compiler error for this operation and I don't understand why: there is no `operator+ (const string& lhs, int rhs);`. Is int silently casted to char? (Compiling with gcc  Red Hat 4.1.2 and -Wall switch).

And, most important, how do we find all the lines where int added to std::string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your colleague only used integer literals, these will be converted to `char` - You will however see a warning if the value of the integer is too big. The operator that gets called is

```
std::string operator+(const std::string &s, char c); // actually it's basic_string<> with some CharT...
```

Or the `+=` variant ;)

On how to find all the calls. You could compile (w/o inlining) all the code, `objdump` it, `grep` for all the operator occurrences and use `addr2line` on the filtered addresses:

```
$ cat string-plus.cpp
#include <string>
int main()
{
 std::string a = "moof ";
 a += 192371;
}
$ g++ -g string-plus.cpp
string-plus.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
string-plus.cpp:5: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion
$ objdump -Cd a.out | \
    grep 'call.*std::string::operator+=(char)@plt' | \
    tr -d ' ' | \
    cut -d: -f1 | \
    xargs addr2line -Cfe string-plus
main
??:0
```

This however hasn't given me the line number... At least the call site is there ;)

The `-C` switch enables c++ name demangling. Which can also be done manually with binutls [`c++filt`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html#c_002b_002bfilt).

---

Funnily enough, there *is* a definition of `operator+` for `string` and `char`, but only when using `operator+=` the integer literal is converted to `char`, I have to pass a `char` literal (or value) for `operator+` to be used.

---

**To find the mangled name of your operator**:

```
$ cat a.cpp
#include <string>
int main()
{
  std::string a = "moof ";
  a = a + char(1);
}
$ g++ a.cpp
$ objdump -t a.out | c++filt | grep operator+ | cut -d ' ' -f1
08048780
$ objdump -t a.out | grep 0804878
08048780  w    F .text  00000067              _ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEESbIT_T0_T1_ERKS6_S3_
```

The last one is the name you are searching for - which can be used to grep w/o name demangling.

*I really don't know a better way to do this... :/*

Comment: What's the -C switch stands for? I don't have it in my CentOS objdump.

Comment: It demangles c++ ABI names. Without it, `std::string::operator+=(char)` is named `_ZNSspLEc`.

Comment: Actually, my objdump does have the switch. It's just not listed in the help.

Comment: Jack that may be possible. Don't use it and search for the mangled operator name. Compile a test program that does `str+'a'`, objdump -t a.out|c++filt, take the address of `operator+`, `objdump -t` without c++filt and check for the address to get the mangled name.